# How to conver single Char to Long in C?

Tags: c

I want to convert the single char to long, this is the code:

```
scanf("%s",&a);
length = strlen(a);

for(j = 0; j < length; j++){
    if(isdigit(a[j])){
        int temp = a[j];
        val = (long)temp;

        printf("number: %ld\n",temp);
        Push(&S, val);
    }
}
```

but it's not working as i need, help me guys.

Comment: define "not working"...

Comment: What's not working? Compile time error? Runtime error?

Answer (score 2):

Your computer is most likely using the [ASCII alphabet](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii), which means that the character `'1'` (for example) is encoded as the number `49`.

Fortunately it's easy to convert a character into its corresponding digit, by just subtracting the character `'0'`, like in

```
val = a[j] - '0';
```

This works because the value for the character `'0'` equals `48`, and when you do `'1' - '0'` it's the same as doing `49 - 48` which of course equals `1`.

---

Even if your system isn't using the ASCII alphabet (highly unlikely) the C specification says that digits have to be encoded in a consecutive manner, so this "trick" will work no matter the actual encoding used on your system.

This "trick" is also often used to get a letter ordinal, since in ASCII the letters A to Z and a to z follows the same pattern (as you can see from the linked table). However, this is not guaranteed by the C specification, and there are character encoding schemes that are still in use that doesn't follow that (for example [EBCDIC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)). These encodings are not common, but might still be found on some systems.

Answer (score 1):

To convert an ASCII character to an integer, you need to do `val = a[j] - '0'`.

The temp variable is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

As wrote in all other answers you must use `a[j] - 0x30` or `a[j]-'0'` or `a[j]-48` to have the `int` value of an `ASCII digit`.

BTW your code has another little thing to correct: `%ld` is not the format for `int`. If you compile your code with -Wall you'll get:

> warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]

Use `%d` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `int temp = a[j] - '0';` instead of `int temp = a[j];`

This should work because the character code for numbers (digits) are continuous.

[N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 5.2.1 Character sets

> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the
>   value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than
>   the value of the previous.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this....

```
scanf("%s",&a);
length = strlen(a);

for(j = 0; j < length; j++){
    if(isdigit(a[j])){
        int temp = a[j] - 48;
        val = (long)temp;

        printf("number: %ld\n",temp);
        Push(&S, val);
    }
}
```

To convert into digit you have to subtract 48 from that character, which is ACII value of '0'. When you are printing only a[j] as an integer, it is printing it's ACII value, which can be from 48 to 57 for '0' to '9' respectively. So you have to subtract it to get the actual integer.

Comment: It is better practice to use character literals instead of "magic numbers". More readable and more portable.